# Connected to Wifi router but no internet access

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, internet, router, linux-mint

**Problem**

Connected to my wireless router at home won't give me internet access.

**What happened**

Several days ago I was connected to the Wifi router at home and everything works like a charm. Then I closed my Thinkpad and it was send to hibernate mode. Later at the university I was also able to connect to their WPA2-Enterprise (radius-managed) Wifi.

Back at home, I wake up my laptop, fired up the Wifi connection, got an IP, but then nothing works. I have no internet connectivity.

All ping requests to public IPs and Domain Servers timed out.
The Wifi router was also not reachable via ping (which may be an security feature).

**Things done so far**

- Reconnected serveral times to the router
- Deleted the credentials of the networkmanager and entered it again
- Restarted the networkmanager using `sudo service network-manager restart`
- Installed wicd and disabled networkmanager at boot by renaming it's startup files
- Inspected `rfkill` to see, if there is something blocking the wireless interface
- Booted a linux live CD to see, if theres any issue to the configuration files

Booting my windows partition and connecting to the wifi router give me internet access as usual.

**System**

Linux Mint 17

wlan0: Intel wifi interface

What else can I do?

Comment: Not a programming question. This question belongs in superuser

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your description, it's not very likely that any of these help, but maybe it's still worth trying.

**What could be wrong?**

- Driver corrupt.
- Connection settings corrupt.
- DHCP corrupt.
- DNS corrupt.
- Wrong MTU settings (in your case unlikely, just in general).

**How to check what's wrong**

- Check for error or warning messages regarding `wlan0` and `DHCP` in `/var/log` files like `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog`.
- Check your IP configuration using `/sbin/ifconfig`. The `inet` address of `wlan0` should be present, not be link-local (`169.254.*.*`), and have a reasonable `Mask`, usually `255.255.255.0`. If you dial-in on DSL or ISDN, your `MTU` should probably be `1492`, not `1500`.
  Example:

  ```
  wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:2e:3a:58:9f
            inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::201:2eff:fe3a:589f/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:106687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:79673 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:107622853 (107.6 MB)  TX bytes:10363345 (10.3 MB)
  ```
- Check *routing setup* using `/sbin/route -n`. Example:

  ```
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
  192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 wlan0
  ```
- If `ping 198.41.0.4` (one of the DNS root servers) succeeds but `ping ietf.org` fails, your DNS setup is bogus.

Comment: `netconfig update -f` fixed my DNS problems. 
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!